# Как проверить вырожденность матрицы

Tags: python, матрицы, графы

Совершенное паросочетание в графе существует тогда и только тогда, когда определитель матрицы смежности графа отличен от нуля. Необходимо узнать, вырождена ли матрица смежности. Если считать определитель с помощью np.linalg.det(m), то из-за округления ответ может быть неправильным. Вопрос: как можно иначе проверить вырожденность матрицы быстро, используя питон?

Comment: Может не из-за округления, а из-за неточного представления чисел с плавающей точкой? Приведите пример неправильного ответа (с матрицу, на которой вы считаете определитель). Возможно, вам следует сравнивать не с нулём, а по модулю с неким ε (Epsilon).

Comment: Если пользуетесь linalg, то проверьте число обусловленности матрицы `linalg.cond`

Answer (score 2):

`np.linalg.det(m)` похоже всего сводится к сведению матрицы к треугольному виду, при больших матрицах сильно падает точность из-за многократных делений

но вычисление определителя - это избыточная операция для вашей задачи

матрица является вырожденной, если

```
A = B * const
```

т.е. один столбец равен второму столбцу, умноженному на какую-то константу

поэтому от этого и можно отталкиваться

```
for i in range(0, n-1):
    for j in range(i + 1, n):
        if check([matrix[i], matrix[j]):
            return true

return false
```

как проверить 2 столбца между собой - можно вычислить разницу столбцов, домноженных на коэффициент:

```
def check(col1, col2):
    # вычислить коэффициент преобразования
    coeff = col[1] / col[2]

    # проверить столбцы
    for i in range(len(col[1]):
        if abs(col1[i] - col2[i] * coeff) > 1e-10:
            return false

    return true
```

поскольку работать приходится с числами с плавающей запятой, то зачастую 0 получиться нельзя, поэтому можно выбрать некоторый предел около нуля, например 1e-10 или 1e-15 - тут надо посмотреть насколько большая точность нужна

В результате по сравнению с вычислением определителя столбцы лишь однократно делятся умножаются на какое-то число, поэтому точность плывет слабо, кроме того уже на середине проверки можно найти одинаковые столбцы и прекратить дальнейший анализ, потому что матрица уже вырождена

Вот полный код:

```
# проверить, можно ли представить один столбец как произведение другого столбца на константу
def check(col1, col2):
    # вычислить коэффициент преобразования
    # при этом надо найти ненулевые значения иначе
    first1 = -1
    first2 = -1

    for i in range(len(col1)):
        if col1[i] != 0 and first1 != -1:
            first1 = i

        if col2[i] != 0 and first2 != -1:
            first2 = i

    # если ненулевых элементов не найдено - выйти
    if first1 == 0 and first2 == 0:
        return True

    # найти коэффициент
    first = max(first1, first2)
    coeff = col1[first] / col2[first]

    # проверить элементы столбцов - можно ли их представить в виде elem2 = elem1 * const
    for i in range(len(col1)):
        if abs(col1[i] - col2[i] * coeff) > 1e-10:
            return False

    return True

# проверить, является ли матрица вырожденной
def is_invertible(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    for i in range(n - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            if check(matrix[i], matrix[j]):
                return True
    return False


matrix1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
matrix2 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [3, 6, 9]]

print(matrix1, is_invertible(matrix1))
print(matrix2, is_invertible(matrix2))
```

Comment: Пытался разобраться в вашем коде, но, к сожалению, не вышло. Функция check: понятно, что там опечатка, не существует переменной col, так что вы имеете в виду - coeff = col1[1]/col2[1]? А потом в этой же функции цикл for I in range (Len(col1))? Если так, то функция не работает... Поясните, пожалуйста, @Zhihar https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/273314/zhihar

Comment: @Pavel Kust, добавил в ответ полный код как может выглядеть такой метод с примерами. Я его не оптимизировал и не уменьшал код, чтобы было понятно что именно делает метод